# PHP-PostgreSQL: pg_connect always returning false (Windows)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I need to connect a PHP script to a database made in PostgreSQL, with PgAdminIII (installed with Bitnami). Whatever change I could make, the pg_connect function will always return false (no error at all, just returning a false valor, so that it shows the "Didn't connect" message I put in my code).
The server created in PgAdmin is connected as well.
Here's the source...at least last version:

```
    $con = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=example user=postgres password=********");
if (!$con) 
    die("Didn't connect");
```

Comment: For errors to appear, you would need to enable it in the ini... but you can always ask for it with [`pg_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php)

Comment: Problem: pg_last_error() doesn't make any act.